# Dynamic updates of Google maps? (Using for example KML)

Tags: google-maps

I have a KML-file with lots of data in it. I would like to show the data in a google map (or something similair) When the KML-file updates, I would like the google map to update. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What to you mean KML-file updates?
Are you generating the KML from your database so updates means that more points are inserted to your db?

Anyway if that's the case you can construct the browser to **periodically** ask the server if this KML is updated,retrieve it and finally remove the expired file from the map and show the new.

Because as far as i know there is no way you can "**sync**" the KML overlay automatically.